# Apps-Script email permissions approved in script editor, but not in sheet?

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Enterprise (in case that makes a difference).

I have made a spreadsheet with a very short script, just two functions, one that counts the # of unread gmail mails which I called `unread_emails()`, and an `onOpen()` script that copies the current time to a spreadsheet cell (so I know that it's running) and then calls the first function and copies its result to the spreadsheet.

When I first ran this from the Script Editor, it asked me for permissions, and I clicked okay. Since then, the script always runs perfectly if I launch it from the Script Editor, and no longer asks for permissions. *BUT* -- if I just open the spreadsheet, the `onOpen()` function will be halted part-way through, by a permissions error on `getInboxUnreadCount()` -- even though I've already given permission, and it's clearly running on my account (and no, it doesn't ask me to simply re-affirm my permissions, either). If I re-open the Script Editor, everything runs fine.

***How can I get Google Sheets to recognize the permissions that are already assigned here?*** Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the simple script. The `GmailApp` at line 3 is the apparent source of troubles.

```
function unread_mails() {
  Logger.log("starting unanswered func");
  return GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
}

function onOpen() {
  Logger.log("starting onOpen func");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var d = new Date();
  sheet.getRange("B4").setValue(0); // clear
  sheet.getRange('B2').setValue(d.toLocaleTimeString());
  sheet.getRange("B4").setValue(unread_mails());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

from [simple trigger restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions):

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a
>   simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires
>   authorization

it works from the editor, b/c running onOpen() manually isn't the same as having the simple trigger fire off automatically

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of `onOpen()` problems. I've also tried calling `=unread_mails()` as a macro in my sheet -- it has the same issues, but the triggers doc page doesn't describe that usage. And bizarrely, replacing the `onOpen()` simple trigger with an installable trigger for "on open" (yes I changed the function name) doesn't seem to do... anything! Still a puzzle.

Comment: ...but installed triggers based on TIMERS work fine. A puzzle but I think I can work with that...